# java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: Thread already started error when using selectors with SocketChannel

Tags: java, android, multithreading, socketchannel

I am developing an Android app in which there is going to be a lot of network communication between the app and my server.

To Accomplish this, I am using `SocketChannel` with `Selector`, to do the non-blocking IO.

The design I have chosen is, that there will be a `BlockingQueue` on which a 'NetworkIOManager' thread will be waiting. Other threads of the app will be posting messages to that `BlockingQueue` and the `NetworkIOManager` will pickup those messages and send it to the other thread `AsyncRequestHandlerThread`.

Therefore the main responsibility of `NetworkIOManager` thread is to pick the messages from `BlockingQueue` and delegate them to the `AsyncRequestHandlerThread` to send the requests and receive the responses.

Code for `NetworkIOManager.java` :

```
public class NetworkIOManager implements Runnable
{
    private AsyncRequestHandlerThread handlerThread = null; 

    /*
     * 
     * some code here
     * 
     */

    private void vSendRequestUsingSocketChannel(String pTargetURL, int pTargetPort, String pRequestXML, boolean pUseSameConn) {

         // if thread is not created, initialize the thread
         if(handlerThread == null) {
             handlerThread = new AsyncRequestHandlerThread();
         }

         // create a channel to send the request and register it with the selector
         AsyncRequestHandlerThread.createChannelWithSelector(pTargetURL, pTargetPort, pRequestXML);

         // if thread is not started, start it.
         if(!handlerThread.isAlive())
              handlerThread.start();
    }
}
```

The `AsyncRequestHandlerThread` basically creates a `SocketChannel` for each request to be send, with a `Non-Blocking` configuration and registers it with a single `Selector` associated with this thread.

Code for `AsyncRequestHandlerThread.java` :

```
public class AsyncRequestHandlerThread extends Thread {

private static Selector selector = null;

public AsyncRequestHandlerThread() {

    if(selector ==  null)
        vSetSelector();     
}

private static void vSetSelector()
{
    try {           
        selector = Selector.open();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();            
    }
}

public static Selector getSelector()
{
    return selector;
}

public static void createChannelWithSelector(String pTargetURL, int pTargetPort, String pRequestXML) {

    try {
        SocketChannel socketChannel = SocketChannel.open();
        socketChannel.configureBlocking(false);
        socketChannel.connect(new InetSocketAddress(pTargetURL, pTargetPort));
        socketChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_CONNECT, pRequestXML);
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }               
}

public void run() {

    try {

        //  Wait for events with TIMEOUT : 30 secs
        while (selector.select(30000) > 0) {

            try {

                // Get list of selection keys with pending events
                Iterator<SelectionKey> iterator = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();

                // Process each key at a time
                while (iterator.hasNext()) {

                    // Get the selection key
                    SelectionKey selKey = (SelectionKey)iterator.next();

                    // Remove it from the list to indicate that it is being processed
                    iterator.remove();

                    if (selKey.isValid() && selKey.isConnectable()) {

                        // Get channel with connection request
                        SocketChannel sChannel = (SocketChannel)selKey.channel();                    
                        boolean success = sChannel.finishConnect();

                        if (success) {
                            sChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_WRITE, selKey.attachment());
                        }

                        else {

                            // An error occurred; handle it 

                            // Unregister the channel with this selector
                            selKey.cancel();

                        }
                    }

                    else if(selKey.isValid() && selKey.isWritable()) {

                        SocketChannel sChannel = (SocketChannel)selKey.channel();

                         // See Writing to a SocketChannel
                        ByteBuffer requestBuffer = null;

                        requestBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(selKey.attachment().toString().getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));                     
                        sChannel.write(requestBuffer);  

                        sChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
                    }
                    else if (selKey.isValid() && selKey.isReadable()) {


                        // Get channel with bytes to read
                        SocketChannel sChannel = (SocketChannel)selKey.channel();

                        // See Reading from a SocketChannel
                        ByteBuffer responseBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(15);


                        while(sChannel.read(responseBuffer) > 0)    {

                            String responseString = new String(responseBuffer.array(), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
                            Log.d("STATS", responseString);
                        }   

                        sChannel.close();
                    }                               
                }
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch(CancelledKeyException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }           
    }
    catch(IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}   
}
```

The issue I am facing is when I ran the application on my device I got an exception `java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException` on the line `handlerThread.start();` in the class `NetworkIOManager`. When I am debugging this, the application works fine.

I am not able to understand where the problem lies and how can it be resolved ?

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Isn't the exception message self explanatory?

Comment: You're not handling `finishConnect()` returning `false` correctly. If it returns `false` you should just keep selecting. If it *throws an exception* it has failed and you should *close the channel*, not just cancel the key.

Comment: Yeah I get that but the problem is why the `if(!handlerThread.isAlive())` is `true` even if the thread is already running

Comment: thanks @EJP for pointing that out,I will correct that. But I dont think this is creating the issue that I am facing.

Comment: I didn't say it was. If I thought so, I would have posted it as an answer. As it is, it's a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to start the thread after it has exited. You need to rethink your logic. It presently assumes there can only be one such thread and that it never exits, which isn't true.

Comment: I am not able to understand why that thread is exiting ? It should receive events for all the channels that are registered with the `Selector` and continue processing them.

Comment: @Mayank you can try rewriting the check for isAlive() with getState(). `if (handlerThread.getState() == Thread.State.NEW)` then you can also print the thread state to know if the problem is concurrency during starting of the thread or it has terminated and you try to start it after that.

Comment: @helleye I have checked that, basically thread is getting terminated when second time the condition is hit

Comment: @Mayank Then you should follow EJP's advice.